# Pass HttpContext values to dynamic route in Global.asax using asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing, global-asax

I am looking for a way by which i can create my Route programmatically in global.asax file.

My Case scenario: 
I store my Page details in Database Table let us say `Menu` Table as

```
MenuName, MenuID, ParentID, PageURL, PageHandler 
Home, 1, 0, /,Default.aspx 
About Us, 2, 0, /about-us/, About.aspx 
Contact, 3, 0, /contact/, contact.aspx 
Mission, 4, 2, /about-us/mission/, About.aspx
Vision, 5, 2, /about-us/vision/, About.aspx
```

If i code my Route as static in Global.asax file then it works fine as show below.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
    routes.MapPageRoute("en_Home", "default/", "~/default.aspx", false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });

     routes.MapPageRoute("en_aboutUs", "about-us/", "~/about_us.aspx", false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });
}
```

I want  my Routes to be Dynamic so that i can read the URL and PageHandler value from Database and pass it to Route in Global.asax file as

I am not sure how other CMS do it we only create the page in MCS like wordpress of other .Net based CMS and tehy generate Frieldly URL for those page i want similar functionality for my .net webform project so far i am not able to make it work.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {          
    string sURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    //Above Statement give error Say "HttpContext.Current Cant be used in this context

    string PageHandler =  DataProvider.GetPageHandlerByPageURL(sURL);

     routes.MapPageRoute("en_General_Page", sURL, PageHandler, false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });     
 }
```

I am not getting any success in this as i have to pass `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` value to another function so that i can get the page handler. It fails with error `Cant use HttpCotext in this context`

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` doesnt work in Route `RegisterRoutes` function i have to define same in `Application_BeginRequest` but then it has its own issue.

How can i achieve dynamic routing in my case. I am using `ASP.Net Webform 4.5`

I would appreciate help in this regard.

Comment: Are you sure you need the page handler object there? Why don't you just read all rows from the database and call `MapPageRoute` in a loop?

Comment: Can you give me more details on what you are trying to say. It seems to make sense but how will write this in loop.

Comment: From what I understand, you'd like to call the `MapPageRoute` depending on the current request and the mapping in the database. My advice is to read the complete mapping from the database in advance and maps all routes you have in your database when the app starts.

Comment: I get your point, But i am not sure how i will write route as as `routes.MapPageRoute......` is static value. I would appreciate if you can give me a code example. What you are saying make sense and it works then it would be great.

Comment: `foreach ( Record mapping in Database ) routes.MapPageRoute( mapping.Code, mapping.mapsTo, mapping.mapsFrom )`

Comment: I will suggest another opinion for your problem. Did you use "ASP.NET Web Optimization" nuget package? If you can use it and if your project has a good folder structure, then you don't need to do anything. For example, if your real page url is "www.example.com/about/contact.aspx", then you can call it like "www.example.com/about/contact". For default.aspx pages, you don't need to write "default". For example, "www.example.com/about/default.aspx" -> "www.example.com/about"

Comment: I am aware of this but then i have to add physical files under those folder. I have all physical files in one root folder and at present when ever i add a new page to website then i have to add this Physical file and which is quite obvious and then i have to make change to Global.asax file also by adding route for this. Rather than i make change to Global.asax routes i want this to be done programmatically as mentioned in my question